# Export Large data in Yii Stuck server to work

Tags: php, yii2, export-to-csv

I am working in Yii and want to export Large data approx 2 Lack records at a time. Problem is When I try to export data server is stop working and hang all process in system. I have to kill all service and restart server again,m Can anyone tell me appropriate way to export data in csv file.

```
$count = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TEST_DATA')->queryScalar();
$maxRows = 1000:
$maxPages = ceil($count / $maxRows);

for ($i=0;$i<$maxPages;$i++)
{
$offset = $i * $maxRows;
$rows = $connection->createCommand("SELECT * FROM TEST_DATA LIMIT $offset,$maxRows")->query();
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
  // Here your code
}
}
```

Comment: show us your code.

Comment: @Mr.Gandhi Please check I have update code in question.

Answer (score 0):

May be it is because  of the  processing the code without closing the session. When you start the process and do not close session, in the period of processing code, you can not load any page of the site (in the same browser) because of session (it will be busy). It could be accepted as  "hanging of the server" but server is running as it should. You can check it by loading the site on different browser, if it loads, it means the process is running as it should be.

In my experience, i used some table to save processing data (successfully processed offset, last_iterated_time) and see the current state of the processing. Fore example table "processing_data" with variables 'id' (int), 'stop_request'(tinyint, for stopping process, if 1 stop the iteration), 'offset'(int), 'last_iterated_time'(datetime). Add only one record on this table, and on every iteration check the 'stop_request' variable, if it gets the value 1 you can break iteration. And on every iteration you can save current offset value a current datetime. By doing this you can stop processing and continue.

And you can use while (to reduce memory usage) to iterate without counting:

```
set_time_limit(0);
$offset=0;
$nextRow= $connection->createCommand("SELECT * FROM TEST_DATA LIMIT $offset, 1")->queryRow();

while($nextRow) {
    //Here your code

    $processingData= ProcessingData::model()->findByPk(1);
    $processingData->offset=$offset; 
    $processingData->last_iterated_time=new CDbExpression('NOW()');
    $processingData->save();
    if($processingData->stop_request==1) { break; }
    $offset++;
    $nextRow= $connection->createCommand("SELECT * FROM TEST_DATA LIMIT $offset, 1")->queryRow();
}
```